# hibernate query cache with Collection

Tags: hibernate, caching

I have two tables in my Db,Table_cities and Table_Places. Table_cities is the master table for all Cities and Table_Places contains various places present in the city.They are associated with OTM relationship.

The data in these Tables will be mostly static and I want to keep it in cache.I have implemented following for the same. Though things are working fine, I want to know if it can cause any issues as I have read that Query cache may be dangerous for my App as per below link. http://tech.puredanger.com/2009/07/10/hibernate-query-cache/

Please let me know if I should modify it or any other way of doing it.

TableCities Mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.hibernateModel.Cities" table="TABLE_CITIES" schema="CAB">
     **<cache usage="read-only"/>** 
        <id name="objid" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="OBJID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        **<natural-id>** 
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="NAME" />
        </property>
        **</natural-id>**

        <set name="tablePlaces" table="TABLE_PLACES" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
          **<cache usage="read-only" />** 
            <key>
                <column name="PLACES2CITIES"/>
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.test.hibernateModel.Places" />
        </set>

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

TablePlaces Mapping

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.hibernateModel.Places" table="TABLE_PLACES" schema="CAB">
    **<cache usage="read-only"/>** 
        <id name="objid" type="big_decimal">
            <column name="OBJID" precision="22" scale="0" />
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="refId" type="string">
            <column name="ref_id" />
        </property>
        <property name="value" type="string">
            <column name="value" />
        </property>
      </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

ehcache.xml


     <cache name="com.test.hibernateModel.Cities"
    maxElementsInMemory="500"
    eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    />

    <cache name="com.test.hibernateModel.Cities.tablePlaces"
    maxElementsInMemory="500"
    eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    />

     <cache name="com.test.hibernateModel.Places"
    maxElementsInMemory="500"
    eternal="true"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    />
```

Below is my DAO.

```
public LocationsVO getLocation(String cityName) throws Exception {
        Session currentSession = null;
        try {
            currentSession = this.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            currentSession.beginTransaction();
            Criteria crit = currentSession.createCriteria(Cities.class).add(
                    Restrictions.eq("name", cityName)).setCacheable(true);
            List<Cities> cities = crit.list();
            for (int i = 0; i < cities.size(); i++) {
                location=new LocationsVO();
                Cities tempCity = cities.get(i);
                location.setCityId(tempCity.getObjid().toString());
                location.setCityName(tempCity.getName());
                location.setLocations(new ArrayList<Places>(tempCity
                        .getTablePlaces()));

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        } finally {
            if (null != currentSession)
                currentSession.close();
        }

        return location;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you use "read-only caches" you avoid the most mentioned problems described in the linked article (points 1,2 and 3). 
If your data in these Tables is effective static (= only inserts, no updates/deletions while hibernate is up), then using "read-only" cache is the right approach and based on my experience not dangereous at all.